# Angular - Argument of type 'IPgs' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IPgs[]'

Tags: angular

In Angular-12, I am working on dynamic input formarray:

JSON:

```
{
 "message": "Grading Successfully Retrieved.",
 "error": false,
 "code": 200,
 "results": {
    "gradings": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "grade": "TT",
            "classification": "Test A",
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "grade": "MM",
            "classification": "Test B"
        }
    ]
 }
}
```

interface:

```
export interface IPgss {
  pgss: IPgs[];
}

export interface IPgs {
  id?: number;
  grade?: string;
  classification?: string;
}

export class PgsResponse {
  results!: { grading: IPgs[]; };
}

export interface Results { // random name
  pgs: IPgs[];
}
```

service:

```
import { IPgs, PgsResponse } from 'src/app/models/pgs.model';

getPgsById(id: number): Observable<PgsResponse> {
  return this.http.get<PgsResponse>(this.api.baseURL + 'pgs/fetchbyid/' + id, this.httpOptions);
}
```

component:

```
import { IPgs, PgsResponse } from 'src/app/models/pgs.model';
import { PgsService } from 'src/app/services/pgs.service';

pgs!: IPgs;
gradingdata!: IPgs[];
gradingInfoForm!: FormGroup;
data: any;
_id!: number;

constructor(
 private fb: FormBuilder,
 private pgsService: PgsService,
 private router: Router,
 private route: ActivatedRoute,
 private store: Store<AppState>
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this._id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
}

loadGradingById() {
 this.pgsService
  .getGradingSetupById(this._id)
  .subscribe((data: PgsResponse) => {
    this.gradingdata = data.results.grading;
    this.gradingInfoForm.setControl(
      'gradings',
      this.SetExistingGradings(this.gradingdata || [])
    );
  });
 }

SetExistingGradings(gradingSets: IPgs[]): FormArray {
 const formarray = new FormArray([]);
 gradingSets.forEach(c => {
  formarray.push(this.fb.group({
    grade: c.grade,
    classification: c.classification,
  }));
 });
 return formarray;
}
```

I am trying to load and display the formarray data before update.

I got this error:

> ERROR TypeError: gradingSets.forEach is not a function
> at GradingEditComponent.SetExistingGradings

With this highlighted:

> gradingSets.forEach(c => {

and

> this.SetExistingGradings(this.gradingdata || [])

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: `this.pgs` is defined as a single object, not a list. Add the object to a list before assigning it or push it to the existing list.

Comment: Hi, can you share the JSON response data to the question for data verification purpose? Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun - I've updated my code with the JSON. Also note that it loads and display all the data in the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  this.SetExistingGradings(this.pgs || [])
```

use `this.pgs` which is of type `IPgs;`. It's not a `IPgs[]`.
In your component, you have to change the type of

```
pgs!: IPgs;
```

to

```
pgs!: IPgs[];
```

Beside, your `grading` in

```
export class PgsResponse {
  results!: { grading: IPgs; };
}
```

is `IPgs` and not `IPgs[]`. So `this.pgs = data.results.grading;` can't be of type `IPgs[]`.

You should change your `grading` type to `IPgs[]` (if it matches your observable response from `getGradingSetupById`) otherwise you'll have to look for a different solution to correctly type `this.pgs`.

Comment: I changed to export class PgsResponse {
  results!: { grading: IPgs[]; };
}   yet it's not working. Kindly explain. I'm a bit confused

Comment: I've updated my answer because it was not clear enough. In your component, you also have to change the type of  `pgs!: IPgs;` to `pgs!: IPgs[];`. Assuming your return from `pgsService.getGradingSetupById` is indeed a `IPgs[]` this will do the work of course.

Comment: According to your JSON data, my answer will fix your problem. Don't hesitate to accept it and upvote :)

Comment: I have updated the post and the code. The error now is:   ERROR TypeError: gradingSets.forEach is not a function
    at GradingEditComponent.SetExistingGradings    and it highlights  gradingSets.forEach(c => {         and     this.SetExistingGradings(this.gradingdata || [])

Comment: The original question has been answered. Please accept the answer & upvote. You should create a new SO post if you need more help and post the URL here in the comment.